# How to name methods where one takes a single object as input and one takes multiple?

Tags: java, naming

I have two methods in my class:

```
public String widgetToHtml(Widget widget){...}
```

and

```
public String widgetsToHtml(List <Widget> widgets){
    for(Widget widget : widgets){
        widgetToHtml(widget);
    }
}
```

How should these methods be named?

- They could be named the same thing, and overloaded
- They could be named slightly differently with one being 'widget **s** To Html' and the other being 'widget To Html'.

  - They could also be named `singleWidgetToHtml` and `multipleWidgetToHtml`

Follow up questions:

- Would it be different if the method to process a single widget was private?

**Edit**: [Crossposted here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286152/how-to-name-methods-where-one-takes-a-single-object-as-input-and-one-takes-multi)

Comment: I would either overload it or use varargs (though varargs can make life very tricky), but it's just a personal opinion. And if you want to enforce that at least one parameter is passed, do `public String widgetToHtml( Widget first, Widget... rest)`

Comment: In ordinary all variants are applicable, the point is the follow to java method naming convention. IMHO I choose overloading.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/255171)

Comment: Second choice makes more sense.

Comment: And if the method is private, you can pretty much call it what you want. Since it isn't part of the public contract of the class, its name can be changed at any point in the future without wide-ranging consequences.

Comment: I am not a fan of var args, I would go with the widgetsToHtml plural naming. A singular function name that takes a list seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would just name the method

```
public String toHTML(...)
```

and overload the methods. There's no added value in specifying the type of arguments in the method's name.

Would a utility class hold these methods?

Comment: This is an awesome answer.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The varrags allows the method to accept zero or muliple arguments. Before varargs either we use overloaded method or take an array as the method parameter but it was not considered good because it leads to the maintenance problem. If we don't know how many argument we will have to pass in the method, varargs is the better approach.

```
public String widgetToHtml(Widget... widget)
 {...}
```

Comment: But now your method name is singular but might take multiple arguments.